# Is reversing string in python in-place method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, slice

Following is the easiest way of reversing a string in python:

```
    string = 'SHWETA'
    print(string[: : -1])
```

I just wanted to know if this code is executing in-place or taking any extra space.

Comment: This is not in-place, since strings are immutable and return a new object whenever modified

Answer (score 1):

Strings in Python are immutable which means you cannot apply any change to an existing string. Any modifications you apply to a string will return a new string object reflecting those changes.